# Fetch data from core data multiple entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am new to *Objective-C* and *Core Data*. I am working on a small project as part of my learning. I created Core Data with entities such as `Product`, `OrderItem`, `Sales` and `Supplier`.

**Attributes:**

```
Product : product-id, supplier-id, productName, category, subcategory,qty, price,minStock,frequency.
Order : order-id, orderDate.
OrderItem : order-id, product-id,qty,price, total, orderDate.
```

I have created relationships between `Product` and `OrderItem` with `OrderItem` inverse to `Product`.

```
Relationship              Destination         Inverse
ordersItem                 OrderItem           --
```

for OrderItem to Product:

```
Relationship              Destination         Inverse
product                   Product              ordersItem
```

My main issue is how do I display ordered items from OrderItem by joining product as:
**Product-id, ProductName, OrderDate, OrderId, Qty, Price, Total** ?

To achieve above if it is normal sql i could run like "Select product-id, productName, order-id, orderDate, qty, price, total from OrderItem o, Product p where o.product-id=p.product-id"

The same way to fetch from OrderItem using core data i could try:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)loadData{

 // Fetch the OrderItems from OrderItem model through from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self context];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OrderItem"];

//How do i do to get productName from Product
//the relationship is based on "product" from OrderItem to Product
//I need to get productName and add to array list below to display on the screen.

NSMutableArray *orderList =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

orderList =[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

return orderList; 
}
```

I do not have any issue displaying from one entity but my issue is from multiple entities?

Any help or advice would be appreciated?

I am trying to add Product and OrderItems at the same time in the code below but i am having  error "orders.orderToProd = [NSSet setWithObject: entDesc.prodToOrder];" is it the right way ?

```
- (IBAction)cmdAdd:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =[self managedObjectContext];
    Product *entDesc =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //set Product details
    entDesc.productName = self.txtName.text;
    entDesc.category = self.txtCategory.text;
    entDesc.qty=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.txtQty.text integerValue]];

    //add OrderItems details here
    OrderItems *orders=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OrderItems" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    orders.price=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.txtprice.text integerValue]];
    orders.orderQty=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.txtOrderQty.text integerValue]];
    orders.total=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.txtTotal.text integerValue]];

    //orderToProd is the relationship object from orderItem to Product and prodToOrder is relationship from Product to OrderItem

    //I am getting error with this line.  I think it expects for array or comma based items
     //Please help
     orders.orderToProd = [NSSet setWithObject: entDesc.prodToOrder];


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *orderItems = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

returns an array of `OrderItem` objects, and you can access the "product" and "order"
attributes simply using the relationships, for example:

```
for (OrderItem *oi in orderItems) {
    Product *product = oi.product;
    Order *order = oi.order;
    // Display product.productName, oi.qty, order.order-id, ...
}
```

This assumes that you have a relationship `product` from *OrderItem* to *Product*
and also a relationship `order` from *OrderItem* to *Order*.

Note that the attributes `order-id, product-id` of *OrderItem* are redundant,
as the corresponding *Product* and *Order* is given via the relationships.
(In other words, Core Data uses relationships and not "foreign keys".)

---

To your added question: Assuming that `orderToProd` is a "to-one" relationship from
*OrdersItem* to *Product*, you would do the following to establish a relationship
between the newly created objects:

```
Product *entDesc = ...
// ...
OrderItems *orders = ...;
// ...
orders.orderToProd = entDesc;
```

Comment: Thank you Martin!, I will give it a go and let you know the results.

Comment: I am actually confused.  Let say, I add product details to product entity later on i grab any product name from Product entity and add to OrderItem with foreign keys (product-id and Order-id). In core  Data if i don't keep common field in both entity how Core Data knows?

Comment: @user1926649: You just set the relationships, for example `theOrderItem.product = theProduct` adds `theOrderItem` to the order items of `theProduct`, if the relationships and inverse relationships are correctly defined.

Comment: I have reset my relationship and inverse again for Product and OrderItems and tried at the same time to add for Product and OrderItems got error. Please refer to last section of above come. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1926649: It is a bit confusing, because the relationships have different names in your original question and in your added code. - And please describe which relationships are to-one and which are to-many. - I have assumed that Product->OrderItems is "to-many" and the inverse "OrderItems->Product" is to-one. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! Product to OrderItems is one to Many and OrderItems to Product is Many to One.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I will have a go and let you know the result.

Comment: That worked but it keeps coming with the following error every time i added record.

Comment: part 1: *** Assertion failure in[UITableView_endCellAnimationsWithContext:],/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070 CoreData: error: Serious application error.An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (9) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted)

Comment: part 2: and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Comment: @user1926649: Your initial question was how to display attributes of related entities, and I have answered that. - Then you added the question how to create the relationships, and I have answered that as well. - Now you have problems with a fetched results controller (which is not mentioned in your question at all). May I suggest that you start with a new question now? (If this answer helped, it would be nice if you "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.)